# How to measure traffic on OpenWRT 12.04

Tags: openwrt

Since just doing a cronjob every morning, before the router reboots:

```
ifconfig > "`date`.ifconfig.txt"
```

isn't very effective, since after ~4 GByte's the counter in the ifconfig will go to zero.  So if there was ~5 GByte traffic, only 1 GByte will be in the txt file.

**My question:** How can I measure daily traffic with OpenWRT 12.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you `telnet` or `ssh` the router to get the data from  `ifconfig` every minute or so and collect your traffic data. If you use luci then you can read all your statistics on the web interface. Possible is also a solution to get your traffic data by polling via the web interface.

Depending what you need, there is a good info about [OpenWRT Statistical Data Overview](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/statistical.data.overview). I personally like rrdtool. There is also more info [RRDTool](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/statistic.rrdtool).

You'll get more info by googling for `OpenWrt+RRD`